# EMR 5.28 not able to load parquet files on s3

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, parquet

On EMR cluster 5.28.0 reading parquet files from s3 fails with below exception, whereas on EMR 5.18.0 the same works fine.
Below is the stacktrace on EMR 5.28.0.

I tried even from `spark-shell`:

```
sqlContext.read.load(("s3://s3_file_path/*")
df.take(5)
```

But fails with the same exception:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 17, ip-x.x.x.x.ec2.internal, executor 1): **org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileDownloadException: Failed to download file path: s3://somedir/somesubdir/434560/1658_1564419581.parquet, range: 0-7928, partition values: [empty row], isDataPresent: false**
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.AsyncFileDownloader.next(AsyncFileDownloader.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.getNextFile(FileScanRDD.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$parquet$ParquetFileFormat$$isCreatedByParquetMr(ParquetFileFormat.scala:352)
    at** org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildPrefetcherWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildPrefetcherWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:579)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.AsyncFileDownloader.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$AsyncFileDownloader$$downloadFile(AsyncFileDownloader.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.AsyncFileDownloader$$anonfun$initiateFilesDownload$2$$anon$1.call(AsyncFileDownloader.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.AsyncFileDownloader$$anonfun$initiateFilesDownload$2$$anon$1.call(AsyncFileDownloader.scala:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
```

I am not able to find this documented. Has anyone faced this issue on EMR 5.28.0 and was able to fix this?

On 5.28 I am able to read files written to s3 by EMR but reading existing parquet files written by parquet-go throws above exception whereas it works fine on EMR 5.18

Update : 
On inspecting the parquet files ,older ones that work only with 5.18 have missing stats

```
creator:            null 
file schema:        parquet-go-root 
timestringhr:        BINARY SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:21015 SZ:1949/25676/13.17 VC:1092 ENC:RLE,BIT_PACKED,PLAIN ST:[no stats for this column]
timeseconds:         INT64 SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:22964 SZ:1397/9064/6.49 VC:1092 ENC:RLE,BIT_PACKED,PLAIN ST:[min: 1564419460, max: 1564419581, num_nulls not defined]
```

where as those which work on both EMR 5.18 and 5.28 are like

```
creator:            parquet-mr version 1.10.0 (build 031a6654009e3b82020012a18434c582bd74c73a) 
extra:              org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata = {<schema_here>}    
timestringhr:        BINARY SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:3988 SZ:156/152/0.97 VC:1092 ENC:PLAIN_DICTIONARY,RLE,BIT_PACKED ST:[min: 2019-07-29 16:00:00, max: 2019-07-29 16:00:00, num_nulls: 0]
timeseconds:         INT64 SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:4144 SZ:954/1424/1.49 VC:1092 ENC:PLAIN_DICTIONARY,RLE,BIT_PACKED ST:[min: 1564419460, max: 1564419581, num_nulls: 0]
```

This might be causing the NullPointerException .Found a related issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1217 with parquet-mr. I can try including updated version of parquet in classpath or testing on EMR 6 beta to see if that fixes the issue .

Comment: I experience a similar issue after upgrading to EMR-5.29.0 from EMR-5.20.0

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `created_by` value to the footer. I traced one NPE down to the footer/created_by check in Spark. If your are using `xitongsys/parquet-go` , kindly consider this:

```
var writer_version = "parquet-go version 1.0"
...

...
pw, err := writer.NewJSONWriter(schemaStr, fw, 4)
pw.Footer.CreatedBy = &writer_version
```

Comment: I just want to comment, that by adding pw.Footer.CreatedBy in the Go code worked

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your parquet files do not contain rowGroups that have zero rows. You might have to debug through the file using a reader while it loads. We encountered this in AWS Glue getting "illegal row group of 0 rows".

Fix:
We were using the Parquet.net nuget package and restricted it from writing rowgroups if they did not contain data.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely is caused by a lack of IAM permissions for the EMR assumed role to access the S3 location where the files are located.